# Error in routing and function in controller

Tags: laravel-4

In the app/routes.php file i add "Route::resource('cat', 'CatController');"

And this is a CatController code:

```
<?php

class CatController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
         return 'This is cat controller index.';

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return 'This is a form to create new cat !';
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        return 'Show the cat number:' . $id;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

When I call the url: http://www.domain.com/laravel/public/cat/edit, it returns:

Show the cat number:edit

Why it's return the show function content ?!

Answer (score 0):

The URL pattern for `edit($id)` is `/resource/{id}/edit` - you're just using `/resource/edit` which is interpreted as `/resource/{id}`, pointing to the `show($id)` method.

Comment: When i user /public/cat/edit/4564 it get and error

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Wrong order. Read what I wrote (and maybe the documentation) again.

Comment: humm it works but when there is a 2 functions with parameter it return wrong